# Find all dirs/files that have symlinks pointing to them?

Tags: symlink, directory-structure

I am in a situation where I want to delete some cruft, but there might be some symlinks pointing to the cruft, so I don't want to delete those targets.

Is there a command or some switches that will tell me which files and directories have symlinks pointing *to* them? In my case, I'm only concerned about files/dirs in the first level of a particular directory (i.e. no recursion), but a general command might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file does not keep track of the symbolic links pointing to it. Instead, search for symbolic links under your tree and find out which file/dir they point to using `readlink`:

```
find -type l -exec readlink -e -- "{}" \+ | sort | uniq
```

Since `find`'s default behavior is recursion, this will work for arbitrary depth.

Comment: On some systems you may need to use `readlink -f` instead of `-e`.  FreeBSD for example.

Comment: What is the reason to quote the `{}` and the `+` ?  Is it necessary in this context?

Comment: @RobertL You're right, they don't seem to be necessary. I just put them there out of habit.

Comment: `readlink` is not present on  a standard UNIX system.

Comment: @schily True. In that case you can use `stat` to find out the link's target.

Comment: A program named `stat` is not present on a standard UNIX system either. What you can do on a standard system using `find` only is to get all symlinks and all symlinks that do not point to something.